# How to make a script to import 1 csv file and generate simple meshes on coordinates from csv file

Tags: panel, csv

I am very new to scripting. My problem is that I want the panel to look like this:
[image]

My code so far looks like this:

```
import bpy

class plm(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "d"
    bl_label = "whatever"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = 'My 1st '
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text= "generate sphere based on xy positions")
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add")
        row = layout.row()

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(plm)
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(plm)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

I want when the user clicks the icon to browse and select the file and the when it presses the (in this case sphere) button to generate the meshes based on the positions from the file.

I already have code to generate cubes and other meshes.

```
def genc(i,s,x,y):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=0.01, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(x, y, 0), scale=(1,1,1))
    bpy.context.object.scale = s
```

**The only problem is the panel, the icon click.**

Thanks.

Comment: you need to add an Operator class that executes your cvs read and cube gen code and replace `mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add` in you draw function with the name of that class from its bl_idname.

Comment: You also need code for the part of the layout that has the filebrowser input.